# An Exact Sequence of Chow Groups: Fulton Proposition 1.8

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Proposition 1.8 in Fulton's book on Intersection Theory is as follows:

> **Proposition 1.8:** Let $Y$ be a closed subscheme of a scheme $X$, and let $U$ be $X - Y$. Let $i: Y\to X$ and $j: U\to X$ be the inclusions. Then the sequence
> $$ A_kY\xrightarrow{i_*} A_kX \xrightarrow{j^*} A_kU \to 0$$
> is exact for all $k$.

I think that exactness at the left may fail because some subvariety $W$ of $Y$ may fail to be rationally equivalent in $Y$ itself, while being so in $X$, due to the presence of $k+1$-dimensional subvariety $W'$ and an $r$ and $div(r)$ coming from $X$ but not from $Y$. However, my questions are as follows:

1. Is the sequence exact on the left when we replace $A$ by $Z$? More precisely, is
   $$ 0\to Z_kY\xrightarrow{i_*} Z_kX \xrightarrow{j^*} Z_kU \to 0$$
   exact? I get the feeling this is obvious, or else I'm missing something.
2. What are some examples of failure of $i_*$ not being injective (in the original sequence at least, if not in the other)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $Z_k Y \to Z_k X$ is injective, because both groups are freely generated, and $Z_k Y$ is generated by a subset of the generators of $Z_k X$.
2. Hartshorne, *Algebraic geometry*, Example II 6.5.2 considers $X = \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,z] / (xy - z^2)$, the affine quadric cone in $\mathbb A^3$. If $Y = \{y=z=0\}$ is a line, $A_1 Y = \mathbb Z[Y]$ and he proves that $2[Y] = 0$ in $A_1 X$.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question, what are some common situations in which $A_kY\to A_kX$ is injective? In particular, when Fulton defines the first Chern class of a line bundle $L$, he restricts $L$ to a subvariety $V$ to obtain the Weil divisor associated to whatever Cartier divisor $C$ is such that $\mathscr{O}_V(C) = L|_V$. To me it seems like this gives an element of $A_{k-1}V$, but I think there's an easy inclusion into $A_{k-1}X$. So if the subscheme $Y$ in the question is the subvariety $V$, is the map indeed an inclusion?

Comment: (contd.) I think it simply follows from the fact that if some element of $Z_kV$ is rationally equivalent to $0$ in $X$, then if it comes from some $div (r)$ from another subvariety $W$, then one can simply take the intersection of $W$ and $V$ to conclude that the cycle was rationally equivalent to $0$ in $Z_kV$ itself.

Comment: @user940160 That doesn't work, if $W$ is not contained in $V$. Because $W \cap V$ will not be $k+1$-dimensional and $r$ might not define a rational function on $W \cap V$ (it might only have poles along the intersection, or vanish identically).